# How to fetch the processingDetails,fileDetails,suggestions information from the youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am unable to fetch the processingDetails,fileDetails,suggestions information from the youtube api call. I had used API key to fetch these details but it's not working

First I tried this API Call mentioned below, It's working

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=Skk6MBoejgU&key={API_KEY}&part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails,player

When I tried to fetch processingDetails,fileDetails,suggestions information, It's throwing error message

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=Skk6MBoejgU&key={API_KEY}&part=processingDetails,fileDetails,suggestions

Error message: forbidden

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to be connected with your YouTube Channel to get this informations.

In fact, this is private informations, you can only get this informations only from **your** videos.

We can find this information in the doc of [YouTube API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

> forbidden (403)   forbidden
>
> The request cannot access user rating information. This error may
>   occur because the request is not properly authorized to use the
>   myRating parameter.